# Having the same controller code for multiple HTTP methods, is it possible to hide only one of them from Swagger UI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger-ui

The same method and the same route are used for two different endpoints: one is a GET, the other one is a POST. Is there a way to hide only one of them (e.g. just the GET one) from the Swagger UI?

```
[Route("myroute")]
[HttpPost]
[HttpGet] // This is being keep for compatibility purposes (legacy services that are still using it)
```

I tried using the IgnoreApi property (see below) with no luck: it hides both the GET and the POST. Seems like it hides the entire route, no matter the HTTP method.

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not on the same endpoint. The `ApiExplorerSettings` Attribute is for the entire method and cannot be applied to a specific Attribute accompanying the method.

What you can do is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyCurrentMethod() {
    //Do stuff...
}

[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
[HttpGet]
public void MyDepricatedMethod() => MyCurrentMethod();
```

Comment: Nice solution and worked perfectly. Thank you so much!